# Hide Display subcategories on click css

Tags: html, css, hide

I am struggling to figure out how to display/hide sub-category "Auto Parts" when I check/select "Automobiles". I looked through lot of examples posted here but none of them are working for me. Also, the html is from plugin so I don't have much control over it.

Thanks in advance.
/*

```
 <div> 

    <li id="category-3"><label class="selectit"><input class=" category_57" value="3" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="in-category-3"> Automobiles</label>
    <ul class="children">
    <li id="category-14"><label class="selectit"><input class=" category_57" value="14" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="in-category-14"> Auto Parts</label></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

*/

Comment: any code with any uncessfull attempt to share so one can help or advise ?

Comment: I apologize. Updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/n4ko0eeo/66/

In order to use on click in CSS you could accomplish that by using `:checked` then after that use <kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>+</kbd> to make a specific style to another class name.

```css
.category_57:checked ~ ul {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div> 

    <li id="category-3">
    <input class="category_57" value="3" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="in-category-3"> 
        <label class="selectit" for="in-category-3">Automobiles</label>
    <ul class="children" >
    <li id="category-14" class="category-14">
    <input class=" category_57" value="14" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="in-category-14">
    <label class="selectit" for="in-category-3" >Auto Parts</label></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</div>
```

Or using jQuery

Please make sure to import jquery script in your HTML file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
 $("#category-3 label input").click(function(){
   if ( $('#category-3').is('.hideMenu') ) {
  $('#category-3').removeClass('hideMenu');
  $('.children').fadeIn(400);
   }else {
     $('#category-3').addClass('hideMenu');
  $('.children').fadeOut(400);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
    <li id="category-3"><label class="selectit"><input class=" category_57" value="3" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="in-category-3"> Automobiles</label>
    <ul class="children">
    <li id="category-14"><label class="selectit"><input class=" category_57" value="14" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="in-category-14"> Auto Parts</label></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/skos6xbb/40/

Comment: Hi Liamm12. Apparently, I just ran here and saw it worked but when I used the same css property and it didn't worked. I noticed you added a div and reorder the elements in html. As I mentioned earlier, I cannot update html part as it comes from a plugin. Could you please try without changing html.

Comment: Hi Liamm12. The <label> is before first input in original html. If I move the <label> one level up in your code, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Sammy! Why do you want to do this? it's not a good idea to put your input inside a label. I've already set `for="in-category-3"` to your label so it will guide to your input by the id. If you still having troubles consider uploading your full code

Comment: This is the full code. It comes from a plugin. I didn't put label inside. It was inbuilt. That is the reason I am unable to update html code and also get this working.

Comment: Well, why you won't using jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: I can. The example below also has html modified adding "OnClick" function. I am not quite sure how to get it work.

Comment: Thank you. I modified a little bit but it is working now. You saved a lot of my time.

Comment: I'm happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple JavaScript function:

```js
var elem1 = document.getElementById("in-category-3");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("category-14");

elem1.onclick = function() {
    if (elem2.style.display === "none") {
        elem2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        elem2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div> 
    <li id="category-3">
      <label class="selectit">
        <input class="category_57" value="3" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="in-category-3"> Automobiles
      </label>
      
      <ul class="children">
        <li id="category-14">
          <label class="selectit">
            <input class=" category_57" value="14" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="in-category-14"> Auto Parts
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to do it without any modification on html. This is from a plugin so I have no control over html.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code, please check it out. I didn't modified the HTML code.